# Python: Efficient way of plotting a Gausian KDE over (x,y,z) data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikits

I have a value, z, at position, [x,y], and I would like to smooth this plot using a Gaussian KDE. The reason for this is that I would like to create "hotspots" to find the probability of an object being in a similar place.

x,y and z are 1D arrays. X and Y are irregularly spaced.

Scikit KDE's that I've looked at require that each X/Y pair be evenly weighted but I would like to weight it by Z.

I've tried matplotlib's tricontourf(x,y,z) and tripcolor(x,y,z) but the smoothing isn't what I require.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? [scipy.gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)

Comment: Yup, I have. With gaussian_kde you can do three dimensional data but the output is an equally weighted 3 dimensional set. I would like a 2 dimensional output with the Z input being weighted.